# save value taken en $_POST in an array

Tags: php, android, arrays

I'am passing values from java (android) to a web service (php) : the structure should be an array because the webservice take an array and make a serach in that array so how could I passing an array in $_POST :

```
$interet= $_POST['interet'];
```

// must be an array like this : $interet =array('piano','flute','chien');

NB/: the contain of the array is dynamic , it may have One or even ten value

Comment: Yes I'am using json to pass the result of my web service to the java android but i wan't the inverse , take an array from java and pass on $_POST ( I'am using REST)

Answer (score 0):

You can create in Java json:

```
String mStringArray[] = { "piano", "flute", "chien" };

JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(mStringArray));
```

after send it to php server, and in php do this:

```
$array = json_decode($_POST, true);
```

Comment: how to send it in php : if(isset($_POST['array'])){ $array = json_decode($_POST, true);